# How to stop a hardhat node running on localhost?

Tags: localhost, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

I am running a hardhat node on **locahost** using **hardhat version 2.12.5** on a **windows operating system** for learning purpose. At times I close terminals without stopping the running node by **`CTRL+C`**.

Is there a way for me to to stop the node without having to find its PID through **`systemctl`**?

Maybe some npx hardhat command?

I tried to find something useful on hardhat's official documentation but found nothing there. I also tried asking ChatGPT for it and it suggested me to use **`npx hardhat halt`** or **`npx hardhat stop`** commands and none of them have worked for me.

Both the commands gave me the same error message

[image]

Comment: Please see "Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Actually, the process is also terminated when you close the terminal.  Isn't it? What terminal do you use? and how do you launch the hardhat node then?

Comment: @tenbits i start the node from the vscode terminal, from what I know when you close a terminal the process keeps running in the background

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I appreciate your concern. I'd be thoughtful about this in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`kill-port`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kill-port) utility to terminate the hardhat process which is listening at port e.g. `8545`.

```bash
$ npm i kill-port -g
$ kill-port 8545

#or via project install:
$ npm i kill-port
$ npx kill-port 8545
```